# Envelope of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, spline, upper-lower-bounds

For real valued $x$, and $a>0$, I'm looking for an (upper) envelope of the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(a \pi x)}{\pi x},$$
such that the property $f(0)=a$ is still preserved.

The function

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi |x|},$$

is an upper envelope of $f(x)$, but it doesn't fit at the origin. It would be helpful when the envelope is $C^1$ and as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the following possibility, although it is not particularly elegant:

Let $f(x)$ be the sigmoid-like function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}-1 & a \pi x<-\pi/2 \\ \sin(a \pi x) & -\pi/2\leq a \pi x \leq \pi/2 \\ 1 & a \pi x > \pi/2\end{matrix}\right.$$
then 
$$\frac{f(x)}{\pi x}$$
is an upper envelope which fits at the origin.

[image]

Comment: This (nice) approach still contains the function f(x). Nevertheless +1.

Comment: Is there a possibility to fit the function in the gap by a suitable chosen gaussian?

Comment: Possibly. You would want to impose the value at 0, a high enough standard deviation to be above the function everywhere, and continuity conditions at the edge of the gap. A gaussian + constant would give sufficient degrees of freedom to do that.